# How can I make a clean build of microsoft/vscode source tree?

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, open-source, yarnpkg

I am trying to make a clean new build of microsoft/vscode.

Being new to JS, TS, NPM, and Yarn what command do I have to execute to clear all build artifacts and output files and build the code I changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$node --max_old_space_size=4095 ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js compile
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 